# The question about MTW 4-momentum integral expression and lorentz nature

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, integration, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, lorentz-symmetry

In section 5.8 of Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler's "Gravitation" there is a proof that 4-momentum determined as
$$
\tag 1 p^{\mu} = \int T^{\mu 0}\,\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf r , \quad \partial^{\mu}T_{\mu \nu} = 0, 
$$
transformed as 4-vector under the Lorentz transformation (case "c"). The authors proposed the next explanation: in case "b" they proved that an integral 
$$
\tag 2 p^{\mu} = \int T^{\mu \nu}\,\mathrm{d}S_{\nu}
$$ 
doesn't depend on choise of the hypersurface, so without loss of generality they choosed one with $t = const$ with $p^{\mu} = \int T^{\mu 0}\,\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf r$. After that they considered two integrals $(2)$ with hypersurfaces $t = const, t' = const$, but the first has constant $t$ in one Lorentz frame, while the second has constant $t'$ in another frame. Relate to the first frame the $t'$-line of the second surface only has slope in $t-x$ diagram compare to $t$-line. So they added timelike hypersurfaces on infinity and then they got closed surface
$$
\oint T^{\mu \nu} \,\mathrm{d}S_{\nu}. 
$$ 
By the Stokes theorem it is equal to 
$$
\int \partial_{\mu}T^{\mu \nu}\,\mathrm{d}\Omega = 0,
$$
and by another side (I wrote it in the first frame)
$$
\int_{t = const} T_{\mu 0}\,\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf r - \int_{t'} T_{\mu \nu}\,\mathrm{d}S^{\nu} = 0.
$$
So
$$
\tag 3 \int_{t = const} T_{\mu 0}\,\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf r = \int_{t'} T_{\mu \nu}\,\mathrm{d}S^{\nu}.
$$
I don't understand how exactly they made a consequence that this directly leads to the 4-vector nature of $p^{\mu}$ definition given in $(1)$.

I know that in the second frame I also can rewrite the right side of $(3)$ in a form
$$
\int T_{\mu 0}\,\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf r.
$$
So may I write
\begin{split}
\int_{t'} T_{\mu \nu}\,\mathrm{d}S^{\nu} 
&= \int_{t' = const}{\Lambda_{\mu}}^{\alpha}T_{\alpha \beta}'{\Lambda^{\beta}}_{\nu}{\Lambda^{\nu}}_{\gamma}\,\mathrm{d}S^{\gamma}{'} \\
&= {\Lambda_{\mu}}^{\alpha} \int_{t' = const} T_{\alpha 0 }'\,\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf r{'}\\ 
&={\Lambda_{\mu}}^{\alpha}\int_{t = const}T_{\alpha 0}'\,\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf r{'} \\
\Longrightarrow\quad p^{\mu} &= {\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\alpha}p^{\prime\alpha}, 
\end{split}
which completes the proof? Or the completion is another?